# « Un tien(s) vaut mieux que deux tu l'auras » se trouve dans quelle oeuvre de Gilles Corrozet et on l'y retrouve avec ou sans « s » ?

Tags: littérature, possessif, impératif, proverbes

En ce qui a trait à l'aphorisme « [un tien[s] vaut mieux que deux tu l'auras](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/un_tien_vaut_mieux_que_deux_tu_l%E2%80%99auras) » (« Mieux vaut opter pour quelque chose que l’on peut obtenir immédiatement plutôt que pour quelque chose de plus de valeur mais que l’on n'est pas sûr d’obtenir plus tard», Wiktionnaire) popularisé par [La Fontaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_La_Fontaine) (1621-1685) dans sa fable [*Le Petit Poisson et le Pêcheur*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b8610825d/f262.image.r), on doit savoir (grâce à une superbe recherche de Pierre Bouillon<sup>1</sup>) que l'édition originale n'ajoute pas de *s* à *tien* (*un tien*) et que c'est prétendument par erreur justifiée par l'association à un verbe à l'impératif qu'on verrait substantivé le mot avec le *s* (*un tiens*) au 18<sup>e</sup> plutôt que de le voir comme un [pronom possessif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tien)...

[image]
<sup><sup>Montage de *[Fables choisies. Tome 2 / , mises en vers](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1049430k/f122.item) par J. de La Fontaine*, 1755-1759 ; Oudry, Jean-Baptiste (1686-1755) (Illustrateur), Cochin, Charles-Nicolas (1715-1790) (Graveur) ; il ne s'agit pas de l'édition originale de 1668 dont le lien se trouve dans le paragraphe précédent...</sup></sup>

---

Le *Wiktionnaire* recense les deux graphies et indique par ailleurs qu'on doit cet aphorisme à [Gilles Corrozet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilles_Corrozet) (1510-1568) qui se serait inspiré d'un proverbe espagnol « Mieux vaut un prends que deux je te le donnerai ».

- Peut-on identifier l’œuvre de Corrozet qui contient l'aphorisme popularisé par La Fontaine, présenter le passage en question et valider s'il emploie un *s* ou non ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [*Notes sur les anciens dictionnaires de langue française, les mots oubliés, les autographes et la vie qui se fait.*, « un tiens ... ou un tien ? »](http://www.pierrebouillon.com/2009/11/un-tiens-vaut-mieux-ou-un-tien-vaut.html)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans l’édition des *Fables* de La Fontaine par la *Bibliothèque de la Pléiade*, on écrit sans *s*, et l’on ajoute en note<sup>1</sup> :

> Forme ancienne, et régulièrement dérivée du latin, pour l’impératif de *tenir* à la deuxième personne du singulier ; à ne pas confondre avec le pronom possessif *tien* [...]

Il n’y aurait donc pas forcément confusion entre l’impératif et le possessif, simplement fixation de l’orthographe là où elle était plus variable avant.

Pour illustrer la variabilité d’alors, on trouve dès 1660 une présentation de ce même proverbe, dans laquelle *tiens* prend un *s*, dans le livre [*Nouveaux Proverbes espagnols et françois, disposez selon l'ordre de l'alphabet...*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6259343n/f58.image.r=%22que%20deux%20tu%20l'auras%22?rk=85837;2) :

> Mieux vaut vn tiens, que deux tu l'auras.

Par ailleurs, le *Petit Robert* indique le XII<sup>e</sup> siècle comme première attestation. En fouillant un peu, on trouve une note sur un certain Hugues de Rotelande (ailleurs aussi nommé Huon de Rotelande, ou dans les documents anglais le plus souvent Hue de Rotelande) dans une publication de la *Revue anglo-française* datant de 1936 :

> Hugues de Rotelande, de Crédenhill, en Cornouaille, vivait dans la seconde moitié du XII<sup>e</sup> siècle. Son premier travail paraît être le *Roman d’Ypomédon*, fils d'Hermogènes, qui régnait en Pouille. Fait en vers français, il le dit seulement traduit du latin, mais rien n'établit l'existence de ce prétendu original ; et comme Hugues demande pardon des *mensonges* qu'il débite, c'est ainsi qu'il appelle ses fictions, il semble convenir par là qu'il est auteur et non traducteur de son livre. Du reste, comme le dit notre savant abbé, ce trouvère a un talent particulier pour les sentences, et on peut citer celles-ci :
>
> *Ki bien attend, ne mès attend...*
>   *Ki se hâte plus qu'il ne deit,*
>   *Suvent li vient mauvais expleit.*
>   *On dit ke ki munte trop haut,*
>   *Tost pot descendre a mauveis saut...*
>   *Cil ki bien aime, tart oublie...*
>   *Tost est l'oil ovecque l'amur,*
>   *Le Dei la ou l'en sent doiur...*
>   *Or sai bien, n'est mie gabas,*
>   ***Mieux vaut un tiens, ke deux auras.***

Trouver l’original est difficile, on en mentionne une copie au musée britannique. Faute d’y trouver accès, je me rabats sur [un fac-similé](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4208r/f33.image.r=ipomedon) d’une édition allemande de 1889, ***Ipomedon – Ein Französischer Abenteuerroman des 12 Jahrhunderts*** *(Ipomedon – un roman d’avanture français du 12<sup>e</sup> siècle)*, qui semble assez soucieuse du détail orthographique, malgré que la retranscription de la ponctuation apparaît moins rigoureuse :

> Meuz vaut un ‘tient’ qe deus ‘avraz’.

On notera l’utilisation de guillemets, qui sont sans doute apocryphes, mais qui mettent néanmoins en évidence le jeu de miroir qui existe entre les deux apostrophes, dans la mesure cependant où l’on accepte l’impératif plutôt que le possessif.

En fait, cette idée que dans le *tient* autant que dans le *tu l’auras* on puisse voir une parole entre deux interlocuteurs est un puissant argument pour rejeter le possessif.

[Un article en ligne](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/un-tiens-vaut-mieux-qu-un-tien-a117867092), fort intéressant, mentionne *(à défaut d’offrir un lien aux sources)* d’autres attestations, que je tenterai de localiser éventuellement *(la seconde pourrait fort bien être celle de Hugues de Rotelande mentionnée ci-dessus)* :

> « assez vaut miex un tien que quatre tu l'auras » (Aye d'Avignon, fin du XII<sup>e</sup> siècle)
>   « mieux vaut un tien que deux auras » (fin du XII<sup>e</sup> siècle)
>   « Mieus vaut un tien ne font deus qu'on atent » (Adam de Givenchy, XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle)
>   « J'aimeroye, pour le cueur mien, Mieux que tu l'auras, un tien »  (Charles d'Orléans, XV<sup>e</sup> siècle)
>   « Mieux vaut un tenez que deux vous l'aurez » (Dictionnaire français-anglais de Cotgrave, 1673)

On y mentionne par ailleurs que la première édition du *Dictionnaire de l’Académie française*, parue en 1694, à défaut d’ajouter le *s* à *tien*, n’avait néanmoins sûrement pas l’ambition que l’on y voit un possessif, puisqu’on trouve le proverbe à l’article [*tenir*](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/dico1look.pl?strippedhw=tenir&dicoid=ACAD1694&headword=&dicoid=ACAD1694), et non à [*tien*](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/dico1look.pl?strippedhw=tien&dicoid=ACAD1694&headword=&dicoid=ACAD1694) :

> **TENIR**   [...] On dit prov. *Un tien vaux mieux que deux tu l'auras*, pour dire, que La possession d'un bien present quelque modique qu'il soit, vaut mieux que l'esperance d'un plus grand bien avenir & incertain. Et on dit prov. & popul. A un homme de qui on veut se mocquer, en faisant semblant de luy vouloir donner une chose qu'on ne luy donne pas. *Serrez la main & dites que vous ne tenez rien.*

---

#### Références

**Aye d’Avignon**

Voici un lien vers [un très ancien document sur Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b9059916f/f134.item.r=aye%20d'avignon), dont on dit qu’il date [d’environ 1200](https://www.arlima.net/ad/aye_davignon.html) (Gallica, plus vague et plus tardif, indique plutôt 1301-1400, ce qui est très vraisemblablement une lecture informatique de « *XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle* ») et qui serait [un exemplaire unique](https://archive.org/details/ayedavignonchans00gus/page/n11), document dans lequel on peut trouver ceci :

[image]

Sur la ligne du bas, on peut lire, en s’y penchant avec attention :

> Qassez vaut miex .I. tiẽ q̃ .iiij. tu lauras

Voici [un lien vers une édition plus récente](https://books.google.ca/books?id=HvdIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR17&dq=aye+d%27avignon&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL-5nt8eThAhXthOAKHXJ0BTAQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=%22tu%20l'auras%22%20&f=false) pour ceux que ce manuscrit découragera.

**Cotgrave**

Un très beau dictionnaire pour les anglophones désireux de pratiquer leur français, datant de 1673 et pour lequel l’auteur, Cotgrave, prit le temps d’inclure les plus récents travaux de la *récente Académie du Cardinal Richelieu*. [On y trouve](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ISi4M196tl4C&pg=PT574&lpg=PT574&dq=cotgrave+%22un+tenez%22&source=bl&ots=AFr_MHaUnw&sig=ACfU3U03exM2Swreid-E_LjbKiiEH2_tdQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_hum1k-bhAhXCtlkKHR9OBhoQ6AEwBnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=cotgrave%20%22un%20tenez%22&f=false) :

[image]

> Mieux vaut un tenez que deux vous l’aurez ; Prov. *Better one bird in the hand than two in the bush.*

Si le fait qu’un sujet britannique introduise un vouvoiement assez généralement laissé au singulier ailleurs peut être suspect, du moins peut-on néanmoins conclure que ledit sujet britannique, par ses pertinentes traductions autant que par sa remarquable présentation de gallicismes en début de dictionnaire, semblait assez versé en langue française.

---

#### Note

1. <sub>Attirons l’attention cependant sur plusieurs faiblesses qui pourraient entacher la crédibilité des notes de cette édition qui a pourtant habituellement une assez bonne réputation.</sub>

   - <sub>Contrairement à La Fontaine, qui [laissait en minuscules](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57600b/f222.item), on indique dans l’édition citée :</sub>

   > <sub>Un Tien vaut, ce dit-on, mieux que deux Tu l’auras.</sub>

   - <sub>On cite aussi plus loin Corrozet *(Le Rossignol et l’Oiseleur)*, en y mettant à nouveau des majuscules là où l’original n’en comporte pas :</sub>

   > <sub>Mieux vaut un Tien que deux fois Tu l’auras</sub>

   - <sub>Puis vient le tour de Cyrano de Bergerac, dont on cite *Le pédant joué* ainsi :</sub>

   > <sub>mieux vaut un Quiens que deux Tu l’auras</sub>

   <sub>...citation qui semblerait pouvoir justifier un impératif, mais qui introduit une forme verbale [que l’on ne retrouve pas](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6258473t/f586.double.r=tian) dans une édition du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle, qui s’en tient plutôt à ceci :</sub>

   > <sub>vaut mieux un tian, que deux tu l’auras.</sub>

   <sub>On remarquera aussi que les deux premiers mots sont inversés.</sub>

   - <sub>Et finalement une citation d’une édition du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, *Variétés littéraires, tome VII*, dans lequel on trouverait une *Histoire du poète Silus* de [Charles Sorel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Sorel) (né entre 1582 et 1602 (!!)-mort en 1672), où se glisse une malencontreuse coquille qui rend difficile la recherche de la source sur internet. Quand finalement on découvre que le poète s’appelait non Silus mais Sibus, on peut mettre le doigt sur [un fac-similé](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s_Tome_VII.djvu/132) qui nous indique que la citation est de nouveau modifiée dans la Pléiade. L’original se lit ainsi :</sub>

   > <sub>« Vaut mieux un tiens que deux tu l’auras »</sub>

   <sub>La Pléiade nous affirme plutôt :</sub>

   > <sub>« [...] vaut mieux un Tien que deux Tu l’auras »</sub>

   <sub>Citation dans laquelle on retrouve cinq erreurs : les points de suspension après les guillemets ouvrants, la minuscule à *vaut*, les majuscules à *Tien* et *Tu l’auras*, et l’absence du *s* final à *Tien*.</sub>

<sub>À considérer avec une extrême prudence, donc.</sub>

Comment: Peut-être que la note de la Pléiade c'est de ça que discutait la réponse supprimée.  Assurément avec tout ça on en saura davantage que ce qu'on dit sommairement ailleurs. Merci pour la recherche !

Answer (score 1):

Une autre [source](http://les-proverbes.fr/site/proverbes/un-tiens-vaut-mieux-que-deux-tu-l%E2%80%99auras/) indique simplement qu'il « a repris les fables d’Ésope dans son ouvrage *Les Fables du très ancien Ésope* » et qu'il aurait traduit la morale en s'inspirant du proverbe espagnol dont on a fait état dans la question mais ce n'est pas dans la fable « [Du pescheur et du petit poisson](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k143328m/f251.image.r) » qu'on trouve dans une édition très postérieure à la vie de l'auteur :

[image]

Mais plutôt dans « [Du Rossignol & de l'Oiseleur](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k70299v/f150.image.r) » dans une édition de 1542 :

[image]

> Mieulx vault ung tiẽ que deux fois tu l'auras.
>   <sub>Le tilde note la nasalisation notée par le phonème [ɛ̃] en français moderne selon l’IPA.</sub>

À vous de juger de quoi il s'agit ici...

Comment: Je pencherais pour un tilde (~) parfois employé à l'époque pour marquer la nasalisation d'une voyelle, comme le fait aujourd'hui le portugais. Le proverbe espagnol dont il est fait référence est présent plusieurs fois dans le Quichotte de Cervantes (1605/1615), et c'est bien l'impératif que l'on y retrouve à chaque fois : *y que más valía **un toma** que dos te daré*. On trouve plus tôt, en 1542, la même année que l'édition des fables d'Ésope, *Fare fare mas vale **un toma** que dos te dare* (Marqués de Santillana) ce qui signifie **Mieux vaut un prends que deux je te donnerai**.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour les précisions, n'hésite pas à modifier le contenu.