# Meaning of "valoir" in "Mieux vaut tard que jamais"

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

The phrase "Mieux vaut tard que jamais" is translated as "Better late than never". But what is the sense of the word "vaut" in the French phrase?

Comment: *Late* has a better **value** than *never* - It's more valuable to be late than to never show up

Comment: @Rafalon Thanks for your comment. I think it would be better as an answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't post it as an answer because I don't have any reference to back it up

Comment: I recommend using Wiktionary to find out the original verb: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaut

Answer (score 4):

***Vaut*** is the third person singular of the verb *[valoir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/valoir)* (to be worth, to have a value).

The order of the words in that sentence is not the usual one but is typical for a proverb/aphorism.

The words can rearranged to better match modern usage in:

> ***Tard vaut mieux que jamais.*** Literally: "Late is more valuable (lit. is better worth) than never".

which is still literary or the more usual :

> ***Il vaut mieux tard que jamais.*** It is better (to do something) late than (to) never (do it).
>
> *Il vaut mieux faire quelque chose en retard que ne jamais le faire.*

We can see the same *vaut* in other aphorisms:

> *Mieux vaut tenir que courir.*
>
> *Mieux vaut prévenir que guérir.*
>
> *[Un tien(s) vaut mieux que deux tu l'auras.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34845/un-tiens-vaut-mieux-que-deux-tu-lauras-se-trouve-dans-quelle-oeuvre-de-gi)*
>
> *Mieux vaut allumer une chandelle que maudire les ténèbres.*

*Valoir mieux* is a well known French construction attested since the 13th century (Source [The French comparative modal constructions faire mieux de, valoir mieux and falloir mieux](https://www.academia.edu/10384590/The_French_comparative_modal_constructions_faire_mieux_de_valoir_mieux_and_falloir_mieux)) :

> *Miex li vauroit chi demourer
>
> Que prendre la crois d’outremer,
>
> S’il ne se paie netement.*

Ruteboeuf, *Œuvres complètes*, ca 1249-1277. In modern French:

> *Mieux lui vaudrait rester ici
>
> Que partir en croisade
>
> S'il ne s'apaise pas significativement.*

Finally, *Mieux vaut tard que jamais* has a well known *[contrepèterie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrep%C3%A8terie)*:

> *Vieux motard que j'aimais...*

Comment: @jilliagre "Late is better worth than never" is ungrammatical in English. Rafalon's comment on my question phrases it better: "Late has a better value than never".

Comment: @HarryAudus Thanks. I was trying to stay closer to the French sequence of words (I initially wrote "Late worth better...*, then thought to fix it with "Late worths better..." but that didn't work.) Why is *Late is better worth than never*  ungrammatical while *Learning is better worth than houses or land* is fine?

Comment: *Learning is better worth than houses or land* sounds strange today (we'd probably say *learning is worth more than ...*), but it is grammatical because *learning* is a noun, while *late* is not. Similarly *late is worth more than never* doesn't work either.

Comment: @PeterShor But *Late is better than never* would be fine, right ?

Comment: Yes, *late is better than never* is to *better late than never* as *mieux vaut tard que jamais* is to *tard vaut mieux que jamais*, I'd say. For me the interesting question is why the vaut is necessary in the French sentence, or what it adds - what's the problem with *tard, c'est (quand-même) mieux que jamais*?

Comment: @JD2000: I should really let a native French speaker answer this, but my guess is that in English, we don't have a better word to replace *is* in *Late is better than never*, while in French, you have the verb *valoir* which fits perfectly, so of course you use it.

Comment: @JD2000 *Valoir* is not mandatory. *Valoir mieux* is an old and still common French construction but it doesn't add a lot compared to *être mieux*. The issue is perhaps just that English lacks the verb "to worth". For example Spanish has *valer* and uses a lot the very same constructions, e.g. *Más vale ser cabeza de ratón que cola de león*. *Tard, c'est mieux que jamais* is still possible and regular modern spoken French like *Tard, ça vaut mieux que jamais* is too. On the other hand, *Tard est mieux que jamais* is not really natural.

Comment: Thank you. You may well be right about English - where the noun *worth* fits, we do tend to use it, e.g. *a picture is worth a thousand words*.

Comment: Ahem, that's an adjective...

Comment: It may just be that _valoir mieux_ is more set than _to be worth_...